# A Join using MySQLi shows error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a script that is supposed to read from the database and return an array which is used by another function to display a table. However the function is throwing an error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\nu\userClass.php on line 205
```

I don't know what could be the error because I have already created an object for the MySQLi class. Here is my code

```
function getUser($user_id)
        {
            require("config.php");
            //TODO Clean variables
            $dbc = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
            /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
            {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
            }
            $query2 = "SELECT family.Position, food.Meal "."FROM family, food "."WHERE family.Position = food.Position";    
            $result = $dbc->query($query2);
            $row = $result->fetch_array();
            /* close connection */
            $dbc->close();
            return $row;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message seems to say that you have an error in your SQL query.

Try replacing the call to $dbc->query() by the following lines :

```
$result = $dbc->query($query2);
if ($result === false) {
    echo 'MySQL error: ' . $dbc->error;
}
```

This will show you a more detailed error message.

Comment: I want to get the values as an array. How do I do that because when I try to do that and assign the values as an array. I get an error 'Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\nu\accounts.php on line 20'

Comment: Could you show the code you have written on this line 20 ? Manual is always here to, with examples : http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php